# need help understanding a continuity proof

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-explanation

Can someone help with intuition behind this statement :

**statement**

Let $f : [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      0 & x\notin \mathbb{Q} \\
      \frac{1}{n} & \text{if} \, x=\frac{m}{n}\in \mathbb{Q}
   \end{cases}
$$

If $x\in [0,1]$ \ $\mathbb{Q}$, then $f$ is continuous at $x$

**Proof:**

$\forall \varepsilon >0 \, \exists \, N : \frac{1}{N}<\varepsilon$, since $x\neq \frac{m}{n} \forall \, m,n \in \mathbb{N},$ there is some $\delta_k$ such that the interval $(x-\delta_k,x+\delta_k)$ has no points of the form $\frac{m}{k+1}$. let $\delta= \min\{\delta_1,...,\delta_{n-1}\}$. Then the interval $(x-\delta, x+\delta)$ contains no points of the form $\frac{m}{n}$ for $n=2,3,...,N$. Hence if $y\in (x-\delta,x+\delta), |f(y)-f(x)|=|f(y)-0|\leq \frac{1}{n}$ for $n\geq N+1$ so $|f(y)-0|<\varepsilon$ which proves that $f$ is continuous at $x.$

**Question**

Why does there exist a $\delta_k$ such that the interval has no points of the form $\frac{m}{k+1}$?

Answer (score 1):

We know that $x$ is between two numbers divided by $k+1$, meaning $\frac {m_1}{k+1}\leq x\leq \frac {m_2}{k+1}$ for some $m_1,m_2\leq k+1$, then if we take $$\delta_k\leq \min (|x-\frac {m_1}{k+1}|,|x-\frac {m_2}{k+1}|)$$ we get the required the in a $\delta_k$ neighbourhood of $x$, there are no points of the mentioned form.

Comment: Why do we choose $\delta=min\{\delta_1,\delta_2,...\delta_{n-1}\}$

How do we know, for example, there does not exist a $m_1$ such that $\frac{m_1}{10}<\frac{m_2}{1000} \forall m_2$?

If such an $m_1$ exists, then when we choose $y \in \{x-\delta_k,x+\delta_k\} \rightarrow \frac{1}{n}>\epsilon$, so the function would not converge.

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't completely understood your question but I'll answer something and if that doesn't answer it, please explain what you meant. For any number $x$, we have the two closest numbers to it with denominator $k+1$, and if we take the distance between $x$ and the closer one of these two, we are guaranteed not to meet any number with denominator $k+1$ in our set region. If we take it to be the minimal distance of all such denominators (up to $k+1$), then it must be that any of the denominators up to $k+1$ will not be met in the set region.

Answer (score 0):

$x$ is irrational and also once we fix $k$, there are only finitely many $m$ that you can pick.

Hence if a neighborhood of $x$ is small enough, we can exclude those numbers of the form of $\frac{m}{k+1}$.

Comment: Why do we choose $\delta=min\{\delta_1,\delta_2,...\delta_{n-1}\}$

How do we know, for example, there does not exist a $m_1$ such that $\frac{m_1}{10}<\frac{m_2}{1000} \forall m_2$?

If such an $m_1$ exists, then when we choose $y \in \{x-\delta_k,x+\delta_k\} \rightarrow \frac{1}{n}>\epsilon$, so the function would not converge.

Comment: First, I think there is a typo, I think $\delta = \min\{ \delta+1, \delta_2, \ldots, \delta_{N-1} \}$. $\delta_i$ is defined to be small enough such that there is no number of the form of $\frac{m}{i+1}$ in the corresponding neighborhood. By taking the minimum of them, we make sure that any rational number inside the neighborhood, has a denominator that is bigger than $N+1$. that is $f(y)$ is either $0$ or being map to $\frac1m$ where $m \ge N+1$.